# Clicking on a privilege in the Achievements dropdown takes you to the current site's page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

While at Judaism.SE, I recently clicked on the Achievements item and saw that I received the "acceess to moderator tools" privelege at CodeGolf.SE. When I clicked on that tab, I was taken to [J.SE's page for that privilege](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). This was confusing because I don't have that privilege at J.SE, and because the thresholds for the privilege on the sites are different (because CG.SE is in beta and has a lower threshold).

[image]

Comment: Huh. We link badge notifications correctly, but apparently not privileges. Well spotted!

Answer (score 5):

Whoops...

There was a large refactor in our privileges code recently, where I inadvertently introduced this bug (the link is relative to the site you see it on, instead of going to the site where the privilege was actually earned).

With you in the next build.